# want to install Ubuntu 12.04 on Powermac 11,2

Tags: system-installation, powerpc

want to install Ubuntu 12.04 on Apple Powermac 11,2  (G5)
which has GeForce 6600 LE video

what is the necessary text command to enter at boot prompt?

I have tried the regular and alternate CD iso's

thank you in advance if you can help.

Comment: Were they the mac PowerPC iso's http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/precise/release/

Comment: yes. ubuntu-12.04-alternate-powerpc.iso

Answer (score 0):

Just click the enter button and the installation should start. *Make sure that you plug the monitor into the main graphics port, or the monitor may not display anything when you boot into Ubuntu on the CD.* If it dosen't work in the main graphics port then you might need to change a setting file.